# Primefaces Layout resizes by itself and shows a scrollbar after re-sizing browser window

Tags: layout, primefaces

Whenever i re-size the browser, the `Layout` within re-sizes by itself and shows up a scrollbar.

Can this be avoided?

Primefaces version 3.0 thru 3.5

[image]

Comment: Did you set panelgrid's width and height css with pixels?

Comment: sorry i should've said Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. Set `fullPage` = `true`.

```
<p:layout id="layout" fullPage="true">
```